# Си неверное определение кириллических символов при чтении из файла scanf

Tags: c, кириллица

Итак, дело было вечером, делать было нечего. Меня попросили помочь с лабой по Си, и я такой "почему бы и нет".
Задание звучало так: есть текстовый файл, в нём надо убрать все пустые строки, и перед каждой строкой воткнуть порядковый номер, количество слов, количество гласных и согласных. На чистом си я давно не писал, но быстро глянув пару функций, накидал следующий код:

То, с чем сравнивал: (повторений вроде нету)

```
#define is_vowel(c) ( strchr("АЕЁИОУЫЭЮЯAEIUYO", toupper(c)) )
#define is_consonant(c) ( strchr("БВГДЖЗКЛМНПРСТФХЦЧШЩBCDFGHJKLMNPRSTQVWXZ", toupper(c)) )
```

Структура, в которую записывал строки и информацию о них

```
struct TextString
{
   int num;
   int WordCount;
   int ConsonantCount;
   int VowelCount;
   char* text;
};
```

Этим получал количество строк в файле

```
int GetLineCount(char* filename)
{
   FILE* file;
   int lines_count = 0;
   fopen_s(&file, filename, "r");
   if (file != 0)
   {
       while (!feof(file))
       {
           if (fgetc(file) == '\n')
               lines_count++;
       }
       fclose(file);
       return lines_count+1;
   }
   else
   {
       return -1;
   }
}
```

Функция, в которой, собственно, весь цимес: она делает из массива символов структуру

```
void buffToStruct(char*buff,TextString *str)
{
   str->text = new char[strlen(buff)];
   
   for (int i = 0; i < strlen(buff); i++)
   {
       str->text[i] = buff[i];
       if (buff[i] == ' '||buff[i]=='\n')
       {
           str->WordCount++;
       }
       else
       {
           if (is_vowel(str->text[i]))
           {
               str->VowelCount+=1;
           }
           else
           {
               if (is_consonant(str->text[i]))
               {
                   str->ConsonantCount+=1;
               }
           }
       }
       
   }
   if (str->WordCount == 0)
       str->WordCount++;
   
   str->text[strlen(buff)] = '\0';
}
```

Основная функция

```
int main()
{
   /*setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru_RU.UTF-8");*/
   FILE* txtFile;
   const int maxFilenameLen = 30;
   char filename[maxFilenameLen];
   printf("Enter filname (30 chars): ");
   gets_s(filename, maxFilenameLen);
   if (!strlen(filename))
       gets_s(filename, maxFilenameLen);
   const int lines_count = GetLineCount(filename);
   fopen_s(&txtFile, filename, "r");
   
   if (txtFile!=0)
   {
       system("chcp 1251");
       TextString *str = new TextString[lines_count+1];
       int LineNum = 0, charnum = 0; 
       str[0].num = 0;
       str[0].WordCount = 0;
       str[0].ConsonantCount = 0;
       str[0].VowelCount = 0;
       char *buff = new char[500];
       char c;
       while (!feof(txtFile))
       {
           fgets(buff, 499, txtFile);
           
           if (!((buff[0]=='\n') || (buff[0]=='\0') || (buff==NULL)||(strlen(buff)>500)||(buff[0]=='\t')))
           {
               buffToStruct(buff, &str[LineNum]);
               LineNum++;
               str[LineNum].num = LineNum;
               str[LineNum].WordCount = 0;
               str[LineNum].ConsonantCount = 0;
               str[LineNum].VowelCount = 0;
           }
           buff = new char[500];
       }

       fclose(txtFile);
       int nonEmptyLinesCount = LineNum;
       fopen_s(&txtFile, filename, "w");
       for (int i = 0; i < nonEmptyLinesCount; i++)
       {
           fprintf(txtFile, "%d,%d,%d,%d %s", str[i].num, str[i].WordCount, str[i].ConsonantCount, str[i].VowelCount, str[i].text);
       }
       fclose(txtFile);
       printf_s("Ready. File format:\n line num, word count, consonant count, vowel count, text\n");
       system("chcp UTF8");
   }
   else
   {
       printf("Файл не существует!\n");
   }
}
```

Что я пытался сделать:

1. Менял кодировки файлов, как тех, которые нужно читать, так и исходника
2. Пытался выставить другие кодовые таблицы (system("chcp ...")
3. Менял кодовую таблицу консоли (SetConsoleCP)
4. Менял шрифт консоли
5. Пробовал делать проверку через if-else конструкции
6. Плясал с бубном
7. Принёс в жертву немного лёгких
8. Пинал однокурсников
   **-----Вы находитесь здесь-----**
9. Призывал демонов

И каков итог?
Вся латиница вполне адекватно раскидывается по согласным-гласным, но все буквы русского языка, кроме Ш, становятся согласными:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буква Ш схватила биполярное расстройство:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я понимаю, что никто уже давно так не делает, в смысле использования char под русские символы, и.т.д
Я понимаю, что представленный выше код - УГ, и прошу не сильно кидать тапками
Мне было ОЧЕНЬ лень идти на MSDN и искать что-то там, ведь мне за это, возможно, даже не заплатят.
А поэтому, прошу спрятать помидоры, и помочь придумать хотя бы какой-нибудь костыль, который не будет выглядеть как код спустившегося с небес на землю сеньора с 35-летним стажем, а будет хотя бы отдалённо похож на код первокурсника.
И ещё раз, это не С++, это С, поэтому варианты "не страдать и взять вооон ту функцию из С++" - не ко мне.

Comment: По сути, здесь весь использованный код, кроме #include'ов

Comment: Уточнение №2: Я вполне осознаю причины подобного исхода, но не вполне осознаю пути решения проблемы.

Comment: `setlocale(0, "");` пробовали?

Comment: А откуда в си оператор `new`?

Comment: Если вам дозволено использовать стандарт `c99` и выше, то возьмите широкие строки, и работайте с `utf16`.

Comment: @mik.ov, оператор оттуда, что препод не против. Как оно там у них в программе работает - я хз, у самого на первом курсе был то ли си, то ли ++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не понял, каким компилятором вы пользовались. Мой GCC здорово обругал ваш код, поэтому я его немного переписал. Но на суть это не повлияло.

У вас несколько проблем.

1. Вы используете однобайтовые операции `strchr`, `strlen` и `toupper`. Поэтому ваш исходник тоже должен быть в однобайтовой кодировке. Не UTF-8!

Если ваш исходник в utf-8, то строковый литерал `"АЕЁИОУЫЭЮЯAEIUYO"` в бинарнике превращается совсем не в то, что вы предполагаете. И `strchr` будет работать с этим неожиданным образом.

Для того, чтобы `strchr` правильно находил байты в строках с гласными и согласными, символы, которые вы считываете из файла, должны быть в той же самой кодировке.

Поэтому перекодируйте исходник в cp1251 и скомпилируйте его. И убедитесь, что текстовый файл в той же самой кодировке.

2. Рецепт из п.1 поможет, но не до конца. После перекодировки он будет подсчитывать кириллические гласные и согласные только для заглавных букв. Дело тут вот в чём.

Функция `toupper` понятным образом работает только с ASCII. Для всех остальных кодировок нужно бить в шаманский бубен локалей. Так как в вашем коде таких бубнов нет, то для кириллических букв эта функция ничего не делает. Поэтому ваши литералы нужно дополнить маленькими буквами. Не обращайте внимание на превращение is_vowel в функцию - я это сделал, чтобы в отладчике смотреть содержимое литерала. Макро is_consonant тоже работает.

```
const char* vowels = "АЕЁИОУЫЭЮЯAEIUYOаеёиоуыэюяaeiuyo";

int is_vowel(char c) {
    return strchr(vowels, c);
}
#define is_consonant(c) ( strchr("БВГДЖЗКЛМНПРСТФХЦЧШЩBCDFGHJKLMNPRSTQVWXZбвгджзклмнпрстфхцчшщbcdfghjklmnprstqvwxz", c) )
```

Результат:

```
0,2,0,1 Я 
1,1,3,4 понимаю,
2,9,15,12  что никто уже давно так не делает, 
3,9,26,17 в смысле использования char под русские символы, и.т.д 
4,13,26,20 Я понимаю, что представленный выше код - УГ, и прошу не сильно 
5,14,30,20 кидать тапками Мне было ОЧЕНЬ лень идти на MSDN и искать что-то там, 
6,13,34,27 ведь мне за это, возможно, даже не заплатят. А поэтому, прошу спрятать помидоры,
7,15,36,26  и помочь придумать хотя бы какой-нибудь костыль, который не будет выглядеть как код 
8,15,39,27 спустившегося с небес на землю сеньора с 35-летним стажем, а будет хотя бы отдалённо 
9,11,20,16 похож на код первокурсника. И ещё раз, это не С++, 
10,17,31,26  это С, поэтому варианты "не страдать и взять вооон ту функцию из С++" - не ко мне.
```

Я не буду изображать сеньора с 20-летним стажем и писать про утечки памяти. Просто позволю себе заметить, что подсчёт слов по пробелам неверен.

Если в тексте встречаются два пробела подряд, то пустой промежуток между ними будет зачтён как слово. Пробел заканчивает слово только если перед ним не пробел и не начало строки. Заодно пусть "первокурсник" подумает, сколько слов в строке `" , , "`. Ваш алгоритм насчитает два слова, но надо ли учитывать отдельно стоящие знаки препинания как слова? А здесь сколько слов: `"и.т.д."` - одно или всё-таки три?

Comment: Я, в принципе, понимаю, что кроме указанных возможны и ещё многие другие ситуации, в т.ч с различными "глазу невидимыми" символами, и, думаю, одной проверкой на запятые и количество символов в слове (скажем, не менее 1 и это буква) тут не обойтись. Возможно, позднее я доработаю уже для себя алгоритм и выложу сюда. По поводу toupper - а есть нечто аналогичное для двубайтовых?

Comment: @Antidjagger Есть ‘towupper‘, есть функции для чтения и записи широких символов. Также есть функции для работы с многобайтовыми кодировками, mbcs. Но я вам искренне рекомендую с ними не связываться. Там столько неочевидных граблей разложено, что когда вы их успешно преодолеете, ни один вменяемый преподаватель не поверит, что это творчество первокурсника. Лучше неявно захардкодить cp1251, а усилия потратить на операции с памятью и ввод вывод.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказки. Во что поверит преподаватель - сложно сказать, требования у него оригинальные и думает он тоже странно - в исходном тз к другой лабе была сортировка, потом сказал, что нужна группировка... В общем, по ходу дела посмотрим, и ежели чего вдруг - буду гуглить за 'towupper' и прочее, прочее...